# Run Windows 7 and Windows Server Together

Tags: windows-7, windows-server, web-services, virtual-machine

I am running SharePoint Foundation on Windows 7 as a development platform.  I have had some problems with web services not working as a data source.  I was instructed to work with a server platform instead.  How is this done?  Can I install Windows Server on the same machine running Windows 7?   Will I need to transfer VS 2010 and SharePoint designer to this server environment as well?  I don’t have any back up installation media, so if I lose Windows 7, it’s gone.  Can I create a virtual drive and install Windows server on it?  Thank you for any help with this.

Richard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either do a dual-boot scenario where boot from more than one hard drive, or you can run some form of virtualization software (VMWare, Virtual Box, or Virtual PC/Server).  You would then want to install your dev tools on the server.

Comment: VMWare and VirtualBox are your only options for virtualization because SP 2010 requires a 64 bit guest OS and Virtual PC/Server doesn't support this.